# Share path variables from zsh to bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have some setup tooling in zsh that initializes paths, etc.  When I run my setup in my .zshrc I execute

`. <path>/setup.zsh`

Which sources the bootstrapper.  I have coworkers who would rather use bash instead of zsh, but I'd like to share all the work done in the zsh scripts. Is it possible somehow exec the zsh file and get the same path setup?

If I do in `.bashrc`

`zsh <path>/setup.zsh`

Then the stuff executes fine, but no path variables that were exported in zsh get set in bash

Comment: They have to be sourced, which means not using any `zsh`-only or `bash`-only features in the scripts.

Comment: I semi-worked around this by exporting the path to a temp file and having the bash users load and export the paths set up. it doesn't help with aliases, but its not a huge deal

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a question comes up, why you and your colleague work on the server/machine with same user? Linux/Unix is a multi-user OS, you can have different users, and each user has his own config, shell, .xxxrc files.

If you have to work with same user, one way to go is, extract the common configurations like `Variable: PATH etc, Bash functions, alias ...` put it in a shellscript, e.g. `~/.commoncfg.sh` then in your `.zshrc` and `.bashrc` source this file, to make all the configurations (`alias, variables, functions....` work for both shell env.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the impression this is on the same machine. These are shared scripts to be run on each persons environment...

Comment: @devshorts ok sorry for my misunderstanding of the same server part. but you still can extract the shared part out so that the common part could be sourced by different scripts/shells